# How to solve this issue Transaction Issue in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

When I submit my Action for review, it is rejected with the note "Your Action expressly directs users to a website, phone number, mobile app or alternative payment method to complete a transaction."

I am creating a virtual assistant for University that online provides payment of fees in an offline mode not in online mode. I will be very grateful if you guide and help me more on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do payment transactions for an Action, you need to use the [Transactions API or Digital Purchase API](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/) that is provided by Google. You're [not allowed](https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies#transactions) to implement your own transaction/payment system.

Comment: the university only provides the offline mode of doing the transaction by visiting the bank or post office. there is no online mode so in my app i just want to tell the user about the timing of bank and post office. How to do it to pass the review.

Comment: @prisoner Raja vikrant have valid question, Is it possible to make some text change in answer according to google guildline for pass review.